# How do I create a 3-level accordion that loads in a closed-state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a 3 level accordion that loads with all of the parents collapsed.

This has proven very challenging. I'm seeing some spacing issues and the tertiary children will not open.

Take a look @ http://jsfiddle.net/abenjamin/W67wM/2/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

script

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true });
  });
  </script>
```

html

```
 <ul class="accordion">
  <li><a class="head" href="#">1</a>

      <ul class="accordion main">
      <li><a href="#">1 - 1</a>

        <ul class="accordion sub">
          <li><a href="#">1 - 1 - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1 - 1 - 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1 - 1 - 3</a></li>
        </ul>


      </li>
      <li><a href="#">1 - 2</a>

        <ul class="accordion sub">
          <li><a href="#">1 - 2 - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1 - 2 - 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1 - 2 - 3</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">1 - 3</a>
        <ul class="accordion sub">
          <li><a href="#">1 - 3 - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1 - 3 - 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1 - 3 - 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>


 <li><a class="head" href="#">2</a>

      <ul class="accordion main">
      <li><a href="#">2 - 1</a>

        <ul class="accordion sub">
          <li><a href="#">2 - 1 - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2 - 1 - 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2 - 1 - 3</a></li>
        </ul>      

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2 - 2</a>

        <ul class="accordion sub">
          <li><a href="#">2 - 2 - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2 - 2 - 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2 - 2 - 3</a></li>
        </ul>      

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">2 - 3</a>
        <ul class="accordion sub">
          <li><a href="#">2 - 3 - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2 - 3 - 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2 - 3 - 3</a></li>
        </ul>      
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: set up one set of options for outer accordion...and use work with `heightStyle` on inner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the option `heightStyle : "content"` to the accordion constructor. I added this in a bare-bones fiddle and to yours and both seemed to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/STSfB/

```
$(function() {
  $( ".accordion" ).accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true, heightStyle : "content" })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what that plugin does but you can do the same kind of thing with just jQuery.

```
$("a", ".accordion").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent("li").children("ul").first().slideToggle();
});
```

try this.

I swapped some of the html around also.

Edit
That link is the old link

http://jsfiddle.net/W67wM/3/

something like this for the css

```
li > ul {
    display : none;
}
```

Comment: OK...now include jQuery UI CSS....will lose all of the classes that it adds and wrappers